# Find index of a row in a two dimensional Tensor object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Tensor object **dataset_tf** with the following specification:

```
 Tensor("loss/dense_7_loss/Const:0", shape=(214, 9), dtype=float64)
```

I want to find the index of a **y** placeholder object in this object:

```
Tensor("dense_7_target:0", shape=(?, 9), dtype=float32)
```

I used *tf.where* to find the index of the above row:

```
index=tf.where(tf.equal(dataset_tf, y))
```

When I want to access the row through this index

```
row=dataset_tf[index,:]
```

I see the following error message:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0
From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'loss/dense_7_loss/strided_slice/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [?,2], [].
```